# Re-run subscription on input change

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm trying to create a re-frame subscription which reads data from a REST API instead of the local database and saves this data into the database. The REST call depends on other values in the re-frame database (think API-Key) and while this data is available when navigation through the application, it isn't when reloading. I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/Subscribing-To-External-Data.md#some-code

My subscription looks like this (stripped for readability):

`(rf/reg-sub-raw
  :organisation-users
  (fn [db [_ api-token organisation]]
    (when (not (nil? api-token))]
      (ajax/GET
        (str "/some-url/to/get/users/for/organisation")
        {:params {:api-token api-token}
         :handler #(rf/dispatch [:organisation-users-change %])
         :format (ajax/json-request-format)
         :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})}))
    (ratom/make-reaction
      (fn [] (:organisation-users @db)))))`

The subscription gets passed the API-Key and requests the organisation users from the server. It returns a reaction which updates the subscriber in case the `organisation-users` change in the database, which happens as soon as the rest call succeeds.

Within my component, I subscribe to the subscription:

`(defn organisation-page
  []
  (let [api-token (rf/subscribe [:api-token])
        organisation-users (rf/subscribe [:organisation-users @api-token])]
    (fn []
      [:div {:class "columns"}
      ))); stripped`

This code works if I reload the page and after initialization (which initializes the api-token) let the `organisation-page` render. It doesn't work when the `organisation-page` component is rendered immediatly after loading, because the api-token isn't available yet and it doesn't execute the rest call again.

I also tried wrapping the whole subscription into the reaction, but this leads to an infinite loop because the whole reaction gets executed everytime the `organisation-users` change in the database, which executes the rest call again, which triggers the reaction again and so on.

How would I solve this problem "the re-frame way"? One idea I have is only executing the rest call if the `organisation-users` isn't already populated in the database. This might work but I fear I would run into problems if users navigate to the page later on and see old data or if the call does not succeed and users can't initiate a new try by navigating to the page again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved the fetching of the users into an event.

To test it, I faked the response, but note that you can embed ajax calls in events very nicely with [http-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx) (see the commented out event).

Note that you can deref subscriptions immediately because of [subscription caching/deduplication](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/issues/218).

```
(ns simple.core
  (:require [reagent.core :as r]
            [re-frame.core :refer [reg-sub
                                   reg-event-fx
                                   reg-sub-raw
                                   dispatch
                                   subscribe
                                   dispatch-sync]]))

(reg-sub
  :api-token
  (fn [db _]
    (get db :api-token)))

(reg-event-fx
  :api-token
  (fn [{:keys [:db]} [_ api-token]]
    {:db (assoc db :api-token api-token)}))

(reg-event-fx
  :good-organisation-users
  (fn [{:keys [:db]} [_ response]]
    {:db (assoc db :organisation-users response)}))

(def responses {"123" [{:name "Foo"}]
                "456" [{:name "Foo"} {:name "Bar"}]})

(reg-event-fx
  :fetch-organisation-users
  (fn [{:keys [:db]} [_ api-token]]
    (.log js/console "fetching users with api-token" api-token)
    {:dispatch [:good-organisation-users (get responses api-token)]}))

(defn fetch-users! []
  (let [api-token @(subscribe [:api-token])]
    (when api-token
      (dispatch [:fetch-organisation-users api-token]))))

(reg-sub-raw
  :organisation-users
  (fn [app-db [_]]
    (let [fetcher (r/track! fetch-users!)]
      (reagent.ratom/make-reaction
        (fn []
          (get @app-db :organisation-users))
        :on-dispose #(r/dispose! fetcher)))))

(defn organisation-page
  []
  (let [organisation-users @(subscribe [:organisation-users])]
    [:div 
     (when organisation-users
       [:ul
        (for [user organisation-users]
          ^{:key (:name user)}
          [:li (:name user)])])]))

(defn ^:export run
  []
  (dispatch [:api-token "123"])
  (js/setTimeout #(dispatch [:api-token "456"]) 3000)
  (r/render [organisation-page]
            js/klipse-container))


(run)
```

To show that it works, you can view it live at http://app.klipse.tech/?container&cljs_in.gist=borkdude/f228103b2eaa04b92c5b532485fbd2ef

Comment: With your code, if I render the `organisation-page` after the api-token is available, it does work. If the `api-token` is not available yet, it does indeed wait for the token and execute the http request in the back. I can see the `:good-organisation-users` event firing and receiving the correct data. BUT the `organisation-page` does not re-render on it's own. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a sanity check: which Re-frame version do you use?

Comment: That would be `[re-frame "0.9.4"]`

Comment: I discovered some typo and reviewed my answer. Also I added a link to Klipse, there you can see that it works: http://app.klipse.tech/?container&cljs_in.gist=borkdude/f228103b2eaa04b92c5b532485fbd2ef

Comment: I can see it working on klipse, thanks! I'll try to figure out why it's not working in my code!